# Checking a proof using Markov's Inequality

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-pde

the problem I am considering is as follows:

> For every probability space $(\Omega , \mathcal F , \mathbb P)$; every separable $\mathbb R$-Banach space $(V, ||\cdot||_{V})$, and every centered Gaussian distributed random variable $X: \Omega \to V$, it holds that:
>
> $limsup_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} sup_{r \in \mathbb R} \Big[e^{\epsilon r^{2}} \mathbb P \Big(||X||_{V} \geq r\Big)\Big]$ is finite.

What I have tried is to employ Markov's Inequality.

Suppose, $r > 0$. (This positivity enables us to employ Markov's inequality.)

By Markov's inequality, we have:$ \quad e^{\epsilon r^{2}} \mathbb P \Big(||X||_{V} \geq r\Big) \leq \mathbb E(||X||_{V}) \frac {e^{\epsilon r^{2}}}{r}$.

Consequently, first taking the supremum on both side over $r \in \mathbb R$, and then letting $\epsilon \to 0^{+}$, we can conclude that the desired limit is finite since $\quad limsup_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} sup_{r \in \mathbb R} \mathbb E(||X||_{V}) \frac {e^{\epsilon r^{2}}}{r}$ is $0$.

Is my argument okay ??

Please let me know if I am missing something!!

Thanks in advance!!!

P.S. (EDIT):- As ntt commented, if $r=0$, then the result is false.

Comment: If $r\leq 0$ then $e^{\epsilon r^2}P(\|X\|\geq r) = e^{\epsilon r^2}$, then its supremum should be infinity, right?

Comment: Ohh thanks... sorrry sorry !! I missed the modulus. Yuup, you are right. Thanks a ton. The question is the same, replacing $r$ by $|r|$, let me make the edit.

Comment: Since $\lim_{|r|\to \infty}\frac{e^{\epsilon r^2}}{|r|} = +\infty$, you get $\sup_{r\in \mathbb R} \frac{e^{\epsilon r^2}}{|r|} = +\infty$.

Comment: @ntt , thanks !!

Comment: Sorry but still, these calculations show the R.H.S. of the inequality going to infinity. But the concern is about the finiteness of L.H.S. in the limit. Isn't it??

Comment: Yes, the RHS is infinity, also you cannot conclude whether LHS is finite. It's only a remark that you cannot get the finiteness of the LHS via this way.

Comment: Hmm.. So, Markov's inequality is a very bad idea to employ here!! :( :(

Comment: I don't know how to prove it directly. But it is a consequence of Fernique's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernique%27s_theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is obviously false as written, but is true if we restrict the supremum to be over $r\ge0$. As the comments also noted, Fernique's theorem is the way to go. Fernique's theorem states that there exists $\alpha>0$ such that $\mathbb E[e^{\alpha\|X\|^2}]<\infty$. Then for $0<\epsilon<\alpha$ and $r>0$, we have
$$e^{\epsilon r^2}\mathbb P(\|X\|\ge r)=e^{\epsilon r^2}\mathbb P(e^{\alpha\|X\|^2}\ge e^{\alpha r^2})\le e^{-(\alpha-\epsilon)\|r\|^2}\mathbb E[e^{\alpha\|X\|^2}]\le\mathbb E[e^{\alpha\|X\|^2}]$$
where the second to last step uses Markov's inequality. Taking suprema over $r\ge0$ and letting $\epsilon\to0$ completes the proof. Note that you could also fairly easily show that
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\limsup_{r\to\infty}e^{\epsilon r^2}\mathbb P(\|X\|\ge r)=0.$$